# datetimepicker class - with dts_appcanparse style - can't tab out

Tags: windows, visual-c++, datetimepicker

when the user finishes editing, i get the DTN_USERSTRING - begs the question when does the user finish editing? after typing the date, TAB doesn't seem to generate this notification, nor i get dtn_keydown or any other; mouse or pressing ALT seem to do the trick, but i need to make the TAB finish the edit and move to the next control in the dialog and not get stuck in the DTP.. any ideas?

thanks a ton,
srini.

references:
documentation:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb761745(v=vs.85).aspx [^]
the function is called after the user finishes entering the date

similar problem:
see http://www.codeguru.com/forum/showthread.php?p=751286 [^]
(no response)

Comment: Similar problem from 2003: https://forums.codeguru.com/showthread.php?257575-CDateTimeCtrl-need-key-to-end-edit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems that when CDateTimeCtrl dynamically creates CEdit to allow free edit, then it some how looses the ability to receive messages. It cannot even catch VK_TAB when overriding PreTranslateMessage().

Maybe consider to use a different control than CDateTimeCtrl:

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/miscctrl/datetimeeditctrl.aspx

Comment: Found [this](http://www.microsoft.com/msj/0798/controlspy.aspx) article  useful and trying to work on these lines

Comment: The link @srini shared in his 2011 comment is broken but here's a fixed one: https://archive.is/BJ1NY

Answer (score 0):

The [answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68788735/589059) presents a modified `DateTimePicker` that allows freeform editing and maintains the expected Tab key functionality.