# DateTimePicker internal validation

Tags: .net, vb.net

I have such situations in my program often when using regular DateTimePicker supplied with VB.NET 2010 toolbox.

See this:

```
Public Class Form1

    Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

        Me.DateTimePicker1.Format = DateTimePickerFormat.Custom
        Me.DateTimePicker1.CustomFormat = "dd.MM.yyyy."
        Me.DateTimePicker1.Value = "01.09.2016."
    End Sub
End Class
```

Now, I would like to type in this control 31 7 2016 and I can't, at least not easy or as expected.
I persume this is because 31.09 don't exists as valid date but at this point I am still not finished with entering my wished date.

Is here any trick to turn off this internal validation of dtp or any other way to get wanted (described) functionality in given circumstances?

Comment: Anyone who asks what are the benefits of using `MMDDYYYY` over `DDMMYYYY` should be pointed to this question.

Comment: This "benefit" is pretty unusable here where we have native way of using dates in showed format.

Comment: I know, here we use the same date format and have the same "issue".

Comment: If it is so then this is really an "issue". I still belive that MS provides a way for handling it.

Comment: It is just the way DTP works, you have to type "31072016" to get it to automatically jump between the day/month/year fields.  Or use the Tab key to finish the month.  Lots of custom DTP-like controls around, it is a favorite Codeproject.com project.  Or just assume that your user knows how to use DTP, they always figured it out before.

Comment: Yes Hans. After few tryings everyone is able to enter date. My idea is to give them dtp control where they can do that without tryings.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you are using WinForms and the WinForm `DateTimePicker` control is just a wrapper around the native common DateTimePicker control, you can create a derived control to allow your application to parse the input string.  This is done by setting the [DTS_APPCANPARSE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb761728(v=vs.85).aspx#DTS_APPCANPARSE) style on the control.  You set this style by overriding the control's CreateParams property.

When DTS_APPCANPARSE style is set, the native control sends a [DTN_USERSTRING](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb761745%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) notification to the control.  This message is received in the control's `WndProc` method.

The majority of the code shown below is just definitions for the native structures that are used.  The parsing function (TryParse_NMDATETIMESTRING) used in this example, reuses the DateTime.TryParse method to accommodate a format of "dd.MM.yyyy" by changing the Thread culture to "de-DE" as that culture setting supports this format. You can define any parsing logic you want.

```
Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices
Imports System.Globalization

Public Class DateTimePickerCustomParse : Inherits DateTimePicker

    Protected Overrides ReadOnly Property CreateParams As CreateParams
        Get
            Const DTS_APPCANPARSE As Int32 = &H10
            Dim cp As CreateParams = MyBase.CreateParams
            cp.Style = cp.Style Or DTS_APPCANPARSE
            Return cp
        End Get
    End Property

#Region "Native Structures"
    Structure NMDATETIMESTRING
        Public nmhdr As NMHDR
        Public pszUserString As IntPtr
        Public st As SYSTEMTIME
        Public dwFlags As GDT
    End Structure

    Public Enum GDT
        GDT_ERROR = -1
        GDT_VALID = 0
        GDT_NONE = 1
    End Enum

    <StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)> _
    Public Structure SYSTEMTIME
         Public wYear As Short
         Public wMonth As Short
         Public wDayOfWeek As Short
         Public wDay As Short
         Public wHour As Short
         Public wMinute As Short
         Public wSecond As Short
         Public wMilliseconds As Short
    End Structure

    <StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet:=CharSet.Auto, Pack:=1)> _
    Public Class NMHDR
         Public hwndFrom As IntPtr = IntPtr.Zero
         Public idFrom As Integer = 0
         Public code As Integer = 0
    End Class
#End Region

    Private Shared Function TryParse_NMDATETIMESTRING(ByRef nmDTS As NMDATETIMESTRING) As Boolean
        Dim ret As Boolean
        Dim enteredDate As String = Marshal.PtrToStringUni(nmDTS.pszUserString)
        Dim savedThreadCulture As CultureInfo = Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture
        Try
            Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = New CultureInfo("de-DE")
            Dim dt As DateTime
            If DateTime.TryParse(enteredDate, dt) Then
                nmDTS.dwFlags = GDT.GDT_VALID
                nmDTS.st = DateTimeToSYSTEMTIME(dt)
                ret = True
            Else
                nmDTS.dwFlags = GDT.GDT_ERROR
            End If

        Finally
            Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = savedThreadCulture
        End Try

        Return ret
    End Function


    Private Shared Function DateTimeToSYSTEMTIME(dt As DateTime) As SYSTEMTIME
        Dim ret As New SYSTEMTIME
        ret.wYear = CShort(dt.Year)
        ret.wDay = CShort(dt.Day)
        ret.wMonth = CShort(dt.Month)
        ret.wDayOfWeek = CShort(dt.DayOfWeek)
        ret.wHour = CShort(dt.Hour)
        ret.wMinute = CShort(dt.Minute)
        ret.wSecond = CShort(dt.Second)
        ret.wMilliseconds = CShort(dt.Millisecond)
        Return ret
    End Function

    Protected Overrides Sub WndProc(ByRef m As Message)
        Const WM_NOTIFY As Int32 = &H4E
        Const WM_REFLECT_NOTIFY As Int32 = WM_NOTIFY + &H2000
        Const DTN_FIRST As Int32 = -740
        Const DTN_USERSTRINGW As Int32 = (DTN_FIRST - 5)

        If m.Msg = WM_REFLECT_NOTIFY OrElse m.Msg = WM_NOTIFY Then
            Dim hdr As New NMHDR
            Marshal.PtrToStructure(m.LParam, hdr)
            If hdr.code = DTN_USERSTRINGW Then
                Dim nmDTS As NMDATETIMESTRING = Marshal.PtrToStructure(Of NMDATETIMESTRING)(m.LParam)
                If TryParse_NMDATETIMESTRING(nmDTS) Then
                    Marshal.StructureToPtr(nmDTS, m.LParam, True)
                    Exit Sub
                End If
            End If
        End If
        MyBase.WndProc(m)
    End Sub

End Class
```

**Edit:**
There is one particularly annoying thing about using the DTS_APPCANPARSE style and that is that precludes the use of the `Tab` key to leave the control.  This is documented in: [datetimepicker class - with dts_appcanparse style - can't tab out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8012784/datetimepicker-class-with-dts-appcanparse-style-cant-tab-out).  Entered text is sent for validation either by loss of focus or by pressing the `Enter` key.  However, the `Enter` key still leaves the DTP focused with no keyboard way of leaving it.  Additionally, if you `Tab` into the control, it behaves like the standard DTP; pressing the `F2` key puts it into edit mode and selects the entire text.  To address these issues with control defined above you can add the following.

```
Public Property MoveNextOnEnterKey As Boolean = True
Public Property SelectAllOnEnter As Boolean = True

Protected Overrides Sub OnEnter(e As EventArgs)
    MyBase.OnEnter(e)
    If SelectAllOnEnter Then SendKeys.Send("{F2}")
End Sub

Private Sub MoveNext()
    Me.Parent.SelectNextControl(Me, True, True, True, True)
End Sub
```

You will need to replace the `WndProc` method with this:

```
Protected Overrides Sub WndProc(ByRef m As Message)
    Const WM_NOTIFY As Int32 = &H4E
    Const WM_REFLECT_NOTIFY As Int32 = WM_NOTIFY + &H2000
    Const DTN_FIRST As Int32 = -740
    Const DTN_USERSTRINGW As Int32 = (DTN_FIRST - 5)

    If m.Msg = WM_REFLECT_NOTIFY OrElse m.Msg = WM_NOTIFY Then
        Dim hdr As New NMHDR
        Marshal.PtrToStructure(m.LParam, hdr)
        If hdr.code = DTN_USERSTRINGW Then
            Dim nmDTS As NMDATETIMESTRING = Marshal.PtrToStructure(Of NMDATETIMESTRING)(m.LParam)
            If TryParse_NMDATETIMESTRING(nmDTS) Then
                Marshal.StructureToPtr(nmDTS, m.LParam, True)
                If MoveNextOnEnterKey Then
                    Me.BeginInvoke(New Action(AddressOf MoveNext))
                End If
                Exit Sub
            End If
        End If
    End If
    MyBase.WndProc(m)
End Sub
```

Comment: This sounds interesting. I try this code with new, subclassed control but I don't know how to use it. With slight changes like this Dim hdr As NMHDR = DirectCast(Marshal.PtrToStructure(m.LParam, GetType(NMHDR)), NMHDR). If I disable parsing then dtp behaves like common textbox. Can you add to your example how dtp will accept 31.09.2016. as a valid date? After all I can do validating on _Validate or _Leave event handlers.

Comment: @user1697111 -It will never accept it `31.09.2016` a valid date because it is not a valid date.  Your question was how to allow the user to enter it as the base DTP validates each component (day,month, year) as you type it.  This allows the user to enter a whole invalid date and then must validate the whole string. Validation is provided in the `TryParse_NMDATETIMESTRING` method  If you want to change the validation logic, change the logic in that method.  However, it is currently configured allow exactly what you asked.

Comment: Yes, I belive it would be possible to do something with that. Thank you for good ansver.

Comment: @user1697111, you are welcome.  Also, take a look at my last edit.  I addressed some of the weirdness of using this custom control.

Comment: After all your efforts I can't get workable version of what I want. But I learned here something new. After all, it would not be too hard to make my own control from beginning where I would add abbility to temporary enter 31.09, to enter milliseconds too what is sometimes needeed so now I thinking on that way. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

[TnTinMn](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2592875/tntinmn) posted [a great answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39321899), but his code still has an issue with the Tab key not working correctly (even after incorporating his 2017 edits).

Below is my modified, C# version which solves the problem.  It works by capturing the `WM_PARENTNOTIFY` message of `WM_CREATE` to detect when the DateTimePicker's internal textbox is created, and hook's *that* control's `WndProc` to capture keypresses.

```
using System;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Diagnostics;

// See also:
// https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39319609/datetimepicker-internal-validation
// https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43576035/is-there-a-way-to-get-the-handle-of-the-entry-field-in-a-date-time-picker-dtp
// https://wiki.winehq.org/List_Of_Windows_Messages
// https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#system.windows.forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/DateTimePicker.cs
  
public class DateTimePickerCustomParse : DateTimePicker {

  #region Win32 API's and helpers

  const int DTN_FIRST = -740;
  const int DTN_USERSTRINGW = DTN_FIRST - 5;

  const int DTN_WMKEYDOWN = DTN_FIRST - 4; // unfortunately doesn't seem to capture keystrokes in Edit control
  const int EN_CHANGE = 0x0300;
  const int EN_KILLFOCUS = 0x0200;
  const int EN_UPDATE = 0x0400;

  const int WM_PARENTNOTIFY = 0x0210;
  const int WM_CREATE = 0x0001;
  const int WM_DESTROY = 0x0002;
  const int WM_KILLFOCUS = 0x0008;
  const int WM_PAINT = 0x000F;
  const int WM_KEYDOWN = 0x0100;
  const int WM_KEYUP = 0x0101;
  const int WM_CHAR = 0x0102;
  const int WM_COMMAND = 0x0111;
  const int WM_NOTIFY = 0x004E;
  const int WM_REFLECT_NOTIFY = WM_NOTIFY + 0x2000;

  [DllImport("user32.dll", EntryPoint = "SendMessage")]
  private static extern IntPtr SendGetDateTimePickerInfoMessage(IntPtr hWnd, int Msg, IntPtr wParam, ref DATETIMEPICKERINFO info);

  [DllImport("USER32.dll")]
  private static extern short GetKeyState(int nVirtKey); // see https://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32.getkeystate

  [DllImport("user32.dll", EntryPoint = "SetWindowLongW")]
  private static extern IntPtr SetWindowLongPtr32(IntPtr hWnd, int nIndex, IntPtr dwNewLong);

  [DllImport("user32.dll", EntryPoint = "SetWindowLongPtrW")]
  private static extern IntPtr SetWindowLongPtr64(IntPtr hWnd, int nIndex, IntPtr dwNewLong);

  private delegate IntPtr WndProcDelegate(IntPtr hWnd, int message, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);

  private static WndProcDelegate SetWindowProc(IntPtr hWnd, WndProcDelegate newWndProc) {
    IntPtr newWndProcPtr = Marshal.GetFunctionPointerForDelegate(newWndProc);
    IntPtr oldWndProcPtr;
    if (IntPtr.Size == 4) {
      oldWndProcPtr = SetWindowLongPtr32(hWnd, -4, newWndProcPtr);
    } else {
      oldWndProcPtr = SetWindowLongPtr64(hWnd, -4, newWndProcPtr);
    }
    return (WndProcDelegate)Marshal.GetDelegateForFunctionPointer(oldWndProcPtr, typeof(WndProcDelegate));
  }

  struct NMDATETIMESTRING {
    #pragma warning disable CS0649 // suppress "never assigned to" warning
    public NMHDR nmhdr;
    public IntPtr pszUserString;
    #pragma warning restore CS0649
    public SYSTEMTIME st;
    public GDT dwFlags;
  }

  public enum GDT {
    GDT_ERROR = -1,
    GDT_VALID = 0,
    GDT_NONE = 1
  }

  [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
  public struct SYSTEMTIME {
    public short wYear;
    public short wMonth;
    public short wDayOfWeek;
    public short wDay;
    public short wHour;
    public short wMinute;
    public short wSecond;
    public short wMilliseconds;
  }

  [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Auto, Pack = 1)]
  public class NMHDR {
    public IntPtr hwndFrom = IntPtr.Zero;
    public int idFrom = 0;
    public int code = 0;
  }

  [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
  struct DATETIMEPICKERINFO {
    public int cbSize; // technically uint
    public RECT rcCheck;
    public int stateCheck; // technically uint
    public RECT rcButton;
    public int stateButton; // technically uint
    public IntPtr hwndEdit;
    public IntPtr hwndUD;
    public IntPtr hwndDropDown;
  }

  [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
  public struct RECT {
    public int left, top, right, bottom;
  }

  private static bool TryParse_NMDATETIMESTRING(ref NMDATETIMESTRING nmDTS) {
    bool ret = false;
    string enteredDate = Marshal.PtrToStringUni(nmDTS.pszUserString);
    CultureInfo savedThreadCulture = System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture;
    try {
      //System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo("de-DE");
      DateTime dt;
      if (DateTime.TryParse(enteredDate, out dt)) {
        nmDTS.dwFlags = GDT.GDT_VALID;
        nmDTS.st = DateTimeToSYSTEMTIME(dt);
        ret = true;
      } else
        nmDTS.dwFlags = GDT.GDT_ERROR;
    } finally {
      //System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = savedThreadCulture;
    }

    return ret;
  }

  private static SYSTEMTIME DateTimeToSYSTEMTIME(DateTime dt) {
    SYSTEMTIME ret = new SYSTEMTIME();
    ret.wYear = System.Convert.ToInt16(dt.Year);
    ret.wDay = System.Convert.ToInt16(dt.Day);
    ret.wMonth = System.Convert.ToInt16(dt.Month);
    ret.wDayOfWeek = System.Convert.ToInt16(dt.DayOfWeek);
    ret.wHour = System.Convert.ToInt16(dt.Hour);
    ret.wMinute = System.Convert.ToInt16(dt.Minute);
    ret.wSecond = System.Convert.ToInt16(dt.Second);
    ret.wMilliseconds = System.Convert.ToInt16(dt.Millisecond);
    return ret;
  }

  private static int LoWord(int value) {
    return BitConverter.ToUInt16(BitConverter.GetBytes((uint)value), 0);
  }

  private static int HiWord(int value) {
    return BitConverter.ToUInt16(BitConverter.GetBytes((uint)value), 2);
  }

  private static bool HiBit(short value) {
    const ushort HiBit = 0x8000;
    return ((value & HiBit) == HiBit);
  }

  private static int LoByte(short value) {
    return (int)BitConverter.GetBytes(value)[0];
  }

  private static int HiByte(short value) {
    return (int)BitConverter.GetBytes(value)[1];
  }

  #endregion

  public bool SelectAllOnEnter { get; set; } = true;
  public bool TabOnEnterKey { get; set; } = true;
  private bool tabPrev = false;

  private IntPtr editHandle { get; set; }
  private WndProcDelegate editHandler = null;
  private WndProcDelegate oldEditHandler = null;

  static DateTime lastStamp = DateTime.MinValue;
  private static void DebugPrint(string format, params object[] args) {
    return; // comment out to display extended debugging messages
    #pragma warning disable CS0162 // suppress "Unreachable code detected" warning
    var dt = DateTime.Now;
    if (dt > lastStamp.AddMilliseconds(200)) {
      Debug.Print(""); // group into batches for friendlier debugging
    }
    Debug.Print(format, args);
    lastStamp = dt;
    #pragma warning restore CS0162
  }

  protected override CreateParams CreateParams {
    get {
      const Int32 DTS_APPCANPARSE = 0x10;
      CreateParams cp = base.CreateParams;
      cp.Style = cp.Style | DTS_APPCANPARSE;
      return cp;
    }
  }

  protected override void OnEnter(EventArgs e) {
    base.OnEnter(e);
    if (SelectAllOnEnter) SendKeys.Send("{F2}");
  }

  private void MoveNext() {
    this.Parent.SelectNextControl(this, true, true, true, true);
  }

  private void MovePrev() {
    this.Parent.SelectNextControl(this, false, true, true, true);
  }

  /// <summary>
  /// Attempts to gain a handle to the DateTimePicker's internal Edit control.
  /// </summary>
  /// <returns>Returns the handle, or <see cref="IntPtr.Zero"/> if it doesn't exist.</returns>
  private IntPtr GetEditHandle() {

    const int DTM_FIRST = 0x1000;
    const int DTM_GETDATETIMEPICKERINFO = DTM_FIRST + 14;

    var info = new DATETIMEPICKERINFO();
    info.cbSize = Marshal.SizeOf<DATETIMEPICKERINFO>();

    // Alternative method, also works:
    //SendGetDateTimePickerInfoMessage(Handle, DTM_GETDATETIMEPICKERINFO, IntPtr.Zero, ref info);
    //return info.hwndEdit;

    IntPtr p = Marshal.AllocCoTaskMem(info.cbSize);
    try {
      Marshal.StructureToPtr(info, p, false);
      Message m = new Message() { HWnd = Handle, Msg = DTM_GETDATETIMEPICKERINFO, WParam = IntPtr.Zero, LParam = p };
      base.WndProc(ref m);
      info = Marshal.PtrToStructure<DATETIMEPICKERINFO>(p);
    } finally {
      Marshal.FreeCoTaskMem(p);
    }
    return info.hwndEdit;
  }

  protected override void WndProc(ref Message m) {

    // Note breakpoints triggered in this function may freeze the form until you switch to another window (e.g. Ctrl+Esc)

    switch (m.Msg) {

      case WM_REFLECT_NOTIFY:
      case WM_NOTIFY:
        NMHDR hdr = new NMHDR();
        Marshal.PtrToStructure(m.LParam, hdr);
        if (hdr.code == DTN_USERSTRINGW) {
          NMDATETIMESTRING nmDTS = Marshal.PtrToStructure<NMDATETIMESTRING>(m.LParam);
          if (TryParse_NMDATETIMESTRING(ref nmDTS)) {
            Marshal.StructureToPtr(nmDTS, m.LParam, true);
            if (TabOnEnterKey) {
              if (tabPrev) {
                BeginInvoke(new Action(MovePrev));
                tabPrev = false; // in case next time is just plain Enter key
              } else {
                BeginInvoke(new Action(MoveNext));
              }
            }
            return;
          }
        }
        break;

      case WM_PARENTNOTIFY:
        var h = GetEditHandle();
        var lo = LoWord(m.WParam.ToInt32());
        var hi = HiWord(m.WParam.ToInt32());
        DebugPrint("WM_PARENTNOTIFY  wParam: {0}  lo: {1}  hi: {2}  lParam: {3}  h: {4}", m.WParam, lo, hi, m.LParam, h);
        switch (lo) {
          case WM_CREATE:
            DebugPrint("  WM_CREATE  wParam: {0}  lo: {1}  hi: {2}  lParam:  {3}  h: {4}", m.WParam, lo, hi, m.LParam, h);
            DebugPrint("  Detected creation: {0}", m.LParam);
            editHandle = m.LParam;
            editHandler = new WndProcDelegate(EditWndProc);
            oldEditHandler = SetWindowProc(editHandle, editHandler);
            break;
          case WM_DESTROY:
            DebugPrint("  WM_DESTROY  wParam: {0}  lo: {1}  hi: {2}  lParam:  {3}  h: {4}", m.WParam, lo, hi, m.LParam, h);
            if (m.LParam == editHandle) {
              DebugPrint("  Detected destruction: {0}", m.LParam);
            } else {
              DebugPrint("  *** DETECTED DESTRUCTION OF SOMETHING ELSE: {0}", m.LParam);
            }
            SetWindowProc(editHandle, oldEditHandler);
            oldEditHandler = null;
            editHandler = null;
            editHandle = IntPtr.Zero;
            break;
        }
        break;

      // Can be used as alternative to WM_CREATE.  Has advantage of being able to send a DTM_GETDATETIMEPICKERINFO query
      // to be absolutely sure you get the right control, although I haven't seen a case where CM_CREATE had it wrong.
      case WM_KILLFOCUS:
        var h2 = GetEditHandle();
        DebugPrint("WM_KILLFOCUS  wParam: {0}  h: {1}", m.WParam, h2);
        if (h2 != IntPtr.Zero && h2 == m.WParam) {
          DebugPrint("  KillFocus confirmed creation: {0}", h2);
        }
        break;

    } // ...switch(m.Msg)

    base.WndProc(ref m);
  }

  private IntPtr EditWndProc(IntPtr hWnd, int message, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam) {
    DebugPrint("WndProc  {0}  {1}  {2}", message, wParam, lParam);
    switch (message) {

      case WM_KEYDOWN:
        DebugPrint("WM_KEYDOWN  wParam: {0}  lParam: {1}", wParam, lParam);
        // See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/inputdev/virtual-key-codes
        if (wParam.ToInt32() == (int)Keys.Tab) {
          bool shift = HiBit(GetKeyState((int)Keys.ShiftKey));
          // Bit of a hack but BeginInvoke(new Action(MoveNext)) doesn't do anything, neither does this.Parent?.GetNextControl(this, false)?.Focus() or .Select().
          // Also tried several PostMessage() commands.
          string keys = TabOnEnterKey ? "{ENTER}" : (shift ? "{ENTER}+{TAB}" : "{ENTER}{TAB}");
          if (shift) {
            DebugPrint("   SHIFT+TAB detected; moving Prev");
            tabPrev = true;
          } else {
            DebugPrint("   TAB detected; moving Next");
            tabPrev = false;
          }            
          SendKeys.Send(keys);
          return IntPtr.Zero; // indicate keydown handled
        }
        break;

      case WM_KEYUP:
      case WM_CHAR: // note WM_CHAR is the one that causes a beep
        if (wParam.ToInt32() == (int)Keys.Tab) {
          return IntPtr.Zero; // indicate keyup handled
        }
        break;

    } // ...switch(message)

    // Propogate to original WndProc for the edit control
    if (oldEditHandler != null) return oldEditHandler(hWnd, message, wParam, lParam);
    return IntPtr.Zero;
  }

} // ...class
```

There's an option to log window messages to the Immediate Window in case you want to play with overriding other internal behavior of the DateTimePicker.