# Is there a way to get the handle of the entry field in a date time picker (DTP)?

Tags: winapi, datetimepicker

The `DATETIMEPICKERINFO`structure obtained by sending the `DTM_GETDATETIMEPICKERINFO`message has a field `hwndEdit` which might be what I'm looking for. However, I'm getting always `NULL` for it so I'm wondering what's its actual meaning. If not, is there a way to get the handle of the entry field?

[image]

Comment: It's possible the control is created on demand, so it might not exist at the time you're looking for it.

Comment: Sounds like you are asking about your solution. What are you ultimately trying to accomplish?

Comment: Many thanks for the downvote, it encourages me to keep trying to figure out how to ask perfect questions.

Comment: @JonathanPotter, I suspected the same and sent the message while the entry field had the focus but got `null` in that case too.

Comment: At least post the code where you send the message so we know you are setting cbSize correctly.

Comment: @Andres, should I deduce that the message is working for you and you get a valid value of `hwndEdit`?

Comment: Maybe the control implements the editing function itself now rather than using a separate edit control. As @IInspectable asked, what are you actually trying to do? Maybe there's another way.

Comment: @Anders I'm trying to change the aspect of the field, background color, etc. Note however that I'm also trying to understand what does `hwndEdit` refer to. I would prefer not having a struct field whose content isn't clear. Sadly, the reactions to my question discourage candid curiosity in the winapi section.

Comment: Your question is fine but you should have provided some sample code because the control style turned out to be important. Sample code makes it easy for people to spot common mistakes and reduces the time it takes for people to replicate the issue. If your real question was about changing the color then that is what your question should have been about. You can try asking a new question but I don't think there is a easy way if DTM_SETMCCOLOR is not enough.

Comment: @Anders, I understand that it would be better to include the code. The reason I'm reluctant to do so in the winapi tag is because I'm not a C/C++ programmer and every time I've copied actual code I was downvoted and ended up removing my question. This time I will keep it because it received two good answers which could be useful for others.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`hwndEdit` only seems to be valid when the control has the `DTS_APPCANPARSE` style and you **click** the date text with the mouse (I tested this with `OutputDebugString` and a timer). The edit control is created and destroyed dynamically. The `hwndUD` handle is only valid if `DTS_UPDOWN` is set and the `hwndDropDown` is only valid while the dropdown is visible.

It is not called out in the documentation but `DTM_GETDATETIMEPICKERINFO` is marked Vista+ and this often means the feature is only implemented in ComCtl32 v6 so you also have to make sure you have a manifest that requests this version.

To change the color you can try `DTM_SETMCCOLOR` but only `MCSC_BACKGROUND` is documented to work when Visual Styles are active.

Comment: Thank you Anders. I was a aware of the Vista+ requirement and the manifest is good about v6. I will try further with your findings but I guess changing the backcolor when `hwndEdit` is valid won't suffice. Anyway, thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: To fully control the colors you must draw the entire date control yourself.

Comment: I posted a [code snippet here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68788735/589059) that demonstrates how to reliably obtain `hwndEdit` when the child control is created.

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid there is no way to get what you wanted. I just created a simple Win32 application just to test the possibility. If I use the `DTM_GETDATETIMEPICKERINFO`, `hwndDropDown`, `hwndEdit` and `hwndUD` give me `NULL`. If I try to enum child window, well before I do so I check it with Spy++, no luck, there is no child window associated with it.

[image]

Finally, I tried `GetFocus()` and `WindowFromPoint()`, both give me the `HWND` of the `DateTimePicker` itself only.

Here is my testing code:

```
#pragma comment(lib, "comctl32.lib")
#include <windows.h>
#include <tchar.h>
#include <commctrl.h>

enum MYID {
    MYID_FIRST = WM_APP,
    MYID_DTP
};

LPCTSTR const g_MyWndClass = _T("DTPTest");
LPCTSTR const g_MyWndTitle = _T("DTPTest");

LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM);
void OnWindowCreate(HWND);
void OnTimer(HWND);

int APIENTRY WinMain(HINSTANCE, HINSTANCE, LPSTR, int nCmdShow)
{
    INITCOMMONCONTROLSEX icex{};
    icex.dwSize = sizeof(icex);
    icex.dwICC = ICC_DATE_CLASSES;
    InitCommonControlsEx(&icex);
    WNDCLASSEX wcex{};
    wcex.cbSize = sizeof(wcex);
    wcex.hbrBackground = GetSysColorBrush(COLOR_3DFACE);
    wcex.hCursor = LoadCursor(nullptr, IDC_ARROW);
    wcex.lpfnWndProc = WndProc;
    wcex.lpszClassName = g_MyWndClass;
    wcex.style = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW;
    RegisterClassEx(&wcex);
    HWND hwnd = CreateWindowEx(0,
        g_MyWndClass, g_MyWndTitle,
        WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,
        CW_USEDEFAULT, 0, 600, 400,
        nullptr, nullptr, nullptr, nullptr);
    if (!hwnd) { return 99; }
    SetTimer(hwnd, 0, 100, nullptr);
    ShowWindow(hwnd, nCmdShow);
    MSG msg{};
    while (GetMessage(&msg, nullptr, 0, 0)) {
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }
    return static_cast<int>(msg.wParam);
}

LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hwnd, UINT msg, WPARAM w, LPARAM l)
{
    switch (msg) {
    case WM_CREATE:
        OnWindowCreate(hwnd);
        break;
    case WM_TIMER:
        OnTimer(hwnd);
        break;
    case WM_DESTROY:
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        break;
    default:
        return DefWindowProc(hwnd, msg, w, l);
    }
    return 0;
}

void OnWindowCreate(HWND hwnd)
{
    HWND hwndDTP = CreateWindowEx(0, DATETIMEPICK_CLASS, nullptr,
        WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | DTS_SHOWNONE,
        20, 50, 220, 20,
        hwnd, reinterpret_cast<HMENU>(MYID_DTP), nullptr, nullptr);
    DATETIMEPICKERINFO info{};
    info.cbSize = sizeof(DATETIMEPICKERINFO);
    SendMessage(hwndDTP, DTM_GETDATETIMEPICKERINFO, 0,
        reinterpret_cast<LPARAM>(&info));
    if (!info.hwndDropDown && !info.hwndEdit && !info.hwndUD)
    {
        MessageBox(hwnd, _T("No luck with DTM_GETDATETIMEPICKERINFO"),
            nullptr, MB_ICONERROR);
    }
}

void OnTimer(HWND hwnd)
{
    POINT pt{};
    GetCursorPos(&pt);
    HWND hwndPoint = WindowFromPoint(pt);
    HWND hwndFocus = GetFocus();
    TCHAR buf[99]{};
    wsprintf(buf, _T("Pointing at %p, focusing %p"),
        hwndPoint, hwndFocus);
    SetWindowText(hwnd, buf);
}
```

Comment: I've tried when the calendar is displayed and I've gotten a valid handle for `hwndDropDown` (see Jonathan Potter's comment below the question). The problem seems to be with `hwndEdit`.