# Get selected value from DateTimePicker

Tags: vb.net, winforms, datetimepicker

I would like to get selected value from `DateTimePicker` in VB (If I select only day value then I would like to get only selected day value.)

[image]

In this image I have selected (blue marked) year value from this `DateTimePicker`. So I need only this year value.

In the case of `TextBox` I can get selected value using

```
TextEndTime.SelectedText
```

Is there any syntax or approach to get selected value from `DateTimePicker`?

Comment: So this is a TextBox right? And the DateTime is in the format yyyy/mm/dd? You want to know the value and the type of the value (Year, Month, Day)? I guess I have an idea. if im correct then maybe I have a solution for you.

Comment: No this is DateTimePicker .If this is textbox I think i can select using above Textbox selection approach.For more clarification this application used in tablet so user will select year month or day and change using Manual keypad.

Comment: There's no managed API for that, as far as I'm aware. You might be able to access some protected member(s) that could help if you derived your own class from `DateTimePicker` but that's just a guess.  I suspect that you would need to use the Windows API.  I'm not sure but I would think that there is an edit control inside the `DateTimePicker` that is showing the actual date and you could get the selected text from that just like you would for a `TextBox`.  Not sure of specifics but that gives you an avenue of research.

Comment: The `DateTimePicker` class derives from Control. It doesn't even process `WM_COPY`.

Comment: @Jimi I had a look at [the source code](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/DateTimePicker.cs,118f367684517c5b) yesterday but couldn't produce anything useful. Tbh, I'm not that good with the native stuff. There has to be something there though because how does the year/month/day/etc. get selected separately? And how does the value of each of them get changed when the `ShowUpDown` property is set to true? However, the "UpDown" doesn't seem to be a child control, everything is done _natively_. This is a good question though!

Comment: I think some of the magic happens [here](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/DateTimePicker.cs,1374) _(see the comment four lines before that)_.

Comment: @Ahmed Abdelhameed  A good part of the *magic* is done in `CreateParams`, where the class is set to [`SysDateTimePick32`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb761727%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396). The drop down component part is a `SysMonthCal32`. The controls performs its own mouse capturing. `SetStyle` sets `ControlStyles.UserPaint` and `ControlStyles.StandardClick` to `false` (standard click is handled somewhere else and no right mouse click) The text is updated calling `InvalidateRect`, but `WM_PAINT` + `DrawFocusRectangle` are handled somewhere else.

Comment: @Ahmed Abdelhameed  I tried to send a [`DTM_GETDATETIMEPICKERINFO`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/Controls/dtm-getdatetimepickerinfo) message to the DTP. It returns a [`DATETIMEPICKERINFO`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/commctrl/ns-commctrl-tagdatetimepickerinfo), which should contain the handle of the undelying Edit control (to try and send an `EM_GETSEL` message. But it doesn't return it (empty). The positions of the CheckBox and the UpDown buttons (if any) are returned, though. So, you could get a screenshot of control then... (yep, that's crazy :)

Comment: @Jimi Haha yeah it is. IDK, I feel like there's a simpler way and I'm really curious. Perhaps someone could figure it out, I'll start a bounty.

Comment: [Is there a way to get the handle of the entry field in a date time picker (DTP)?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43576035/3110834)

Comment: @MirJibon, Here is an old article that’s somewhat related to what you want to achieve: http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?573148-RESOLVED-Select-part-of-DateTimePicker-in-code

Comment: Unlike the NumericUpDown most of the internals of the DTP are internal so you cant easily isolate just the Text control to get the SelectedText. One might be able to use PInvoke to get the text but it might be easier to do something else entirely if we could know what the purpose of all this is.  The point of a DTP is that is forces a valid date to be selected.  Just a year is not a date so maybe something else should be used

Comment: @jimi - hwndEdit is only filled when the underlying native DateTimePicker has the DTS_APPCANPARSE style set: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43576035/is-there-a-way-to-get-the-handle-of-the-entry-field-in-a-date-time-picker-dtp/43578107 the problem is if you do this (you can derive the control, override CreateParams, and add DTS_APPCANPARSE to the style), it changes the control's behavior and doesn't select things the same way... So I don't believe there's a solution

Comment: @Simon Mourier  That's one of the first tests I made. I wanted to see whether Spy++ could get the handle of the Edit control in this *mode*. Doesn't happen. The DTP is always *child-less* (excluding the `UpDown` and `CheckBox` controls, when enabled). `DATETIMEPICKERINFO` returns a handle, but, as you said, when `DTS_APPCANPARSE` is set, there are no *entry fields* (whatever they are, it looks like it's painting them), thus it doesn't meet the specifications anymore.

Comment: I don't know the business need behind all of this. But as it looks like the most easy solution would be to capture an image of the control and do some image recognition. I would recommand to search a workaround (using another control or find another way to ask the user his choice)

Comment: In general, you should not rely on an undocumented feature of a control. Because there is no guarantee that feature remains the same always.

Answer (score 3):

As the `DateTimePicker`-control can be manipulated by using the arrow keys, you can use `SendKeys` to change the current selected value.

The following example gets the current `DateTime`-value of the `DateTimePicker` and, after sending the <kbd>↑</kbd> key, compares the value to the new value. At last it resets the `DateTimePicker` to the original value.

So the variable `currSelected` will contain the last `Selection`.

```
Dim currVal As DateTime
Dim newVal As DateTime
Dim valCheck As Boolean
Dim currSelected As Selection = Selection.None

Public Enum Selection
    None = 0
    Year = 1
    Month = 2
    Day = 3
End Enum

Private Sub CheckDTPSelection(dtp As DateTimePicker)
    valCheck = True
    currVal = dtp.Value
    SendKeys.Send("{UP}")
End Sub

Sub RefreshSelection(dtp As DateTimePicker)
    If valCheck Then
        newVal = dtp.Value

        If currVal.Year <> newVal.Year Then
            currSelected = Selection.Year
        ElseIf currVal.Month <> newVal.Month Then
            currSelected = Selection.Month
        ElseIf currVal.Day <> newVal.Day Then
            currSelected = Selection.Day
        End If

        dtp.Value = currVal
        valCheck = False
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub MyDateTimePicker_DropDown(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyDateTimePicker.DropDown
    RemoveHandler MyDateTimePicker.MouseUp, AddressOf MyDateTimePicker_MouseUp
End Sub

Private Sub MyDateTimePicker_CloseUp(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyDateTimePicker.CloseUp
    AddHandler MyDateTimePicker.MouseUp, AddressOf MyDateTimePicker_MouseUp
    CheckDTPSelection(MyDateTimePicker)
End Sub

Private Sub MyDateTimePicker_KeyUp(sender As Object, e As KeyEventArgs) Handles MyDateTimePicker.KeyUp
    If e.KeyValue = Keys.Left OrElse e.KeyValue = Keys.Right Then
        CheckDTPSelection(MyDateTimePicker)
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub MyDateTimePicker_MouseUp(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs) Handles MyDateTimePicker.MouseUp
    CheckDTPSelection(MyDateTimePicker)
End Sub

Private Sub MyDateTimePicker_ValueChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyDateTimePicker.ValueChanged
    Dim dtp As DateTimePicker = DirectCast(sender, DateTimePicker)

    RefreshSelection(dtp)
End Sub

Private Sub Btn_WhatsSelected_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Btn_WhatsSelected.Click
    'Show the current selected value in a MessageBox
    MessageBox.Show(currSelected.ToString())
End Sub
```

Comment: That's clever! Why didn't I think of that? :D Two points though: 1) I would add `CheckDTPSelection` in the `Enter` event as well (to capture the first focus _without mouse_). 2) Opening the drop-down causes `MouseUp` to be triggered, a button up to be sent, and the _visually_ selected day/month to be changed; so I would remove the `MouseUp` handler in `DropDown` and then re-add it in `CloseUp`. Let me add these changes to your answer, if you don't mind.

Comment: Just found out that using the `Enter` event causes the same problem caused previously by `MouseUp` _and_ it fires before `DropDown` _(obviously)_, so I wouldn't use `Enter` for now.

Comment: The problem with SendKeys is it can fail if for some reason the keyboard focus changes.

Comment: @SimonMourier `If dtp.Focused Then SendKeys.Send("{UP}")`? Also, I believe that `CheckDTPSelection` is only called while the DTP is focused anyway. Unless you're talking about the very short period of time between calling the method and `SendKeys.Send()` being carried out.

Comment: @AhmedAbdelhameed - absolutely. When you run production code on thousands of PCs, this is the kind of bug that are very hard to identify and detect. Race conditions happen in the real world. For example if an app is blocked for some reason, and the user is clicking everywhere, a short period of time can become seconds, and the key up can be sent to another app.

Comment: @SimonMourier I agree, you're making a good point. That said, I believe it would be up to the developer to decide if this is acceptable or not depending on the type/size of app (s)he would be working on. Actually, I don't like `SendKeys` any more than you do but considering that there doesn't seem to be another option (other than creating your own DTP), I wouldn't "hate" this too much :D

Answer (score 0):

Hi Everyone and thanks for your tips that the DateTimePicker-control can be manipulated.
I had the selection problem with DateTimePicker , the currently selected item value could not send to a text box, as DTP works only valuechanged event. I spend 4 hours time to find the solution and wrote the following code:

```
Public MyEventCounter As Integer = 0

Private Sub DTPAcquDt_DropDown(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles DTPAcquDt.DropDown
        RemoveHandler DTPAcquDt.MouseUp, AddressOf dtpacqudt_closeup
End Sub
Private Sub dtpacqudt_closeup(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles DTPAcquDt.CloseUp
        AddHandler DTPAcquDt.MouseUp, AddressOf dtpacqudt_closeup
        'Check the Mouse/Keys event counter
        If MyEventCounter > 0 Then
            TxtDtAcqu.Text = DTPAcquDt.Value
            'RESET The Counter
            MyEventCounter = 0
        End If
End Sub
Private Sub DTPAcquDt_KeyUp(sender As Object, e As KeyEventArgs) Handles DTPAcquDt.KeyUp
        If e.KeyValue = Keys.Left OrElse e.KeyValue = Keys.Right Then
            MyEventCounter = MyEventCounter + 1
        End If
End Sub
Private Sub DTPAcquDt_MouseUp(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs) Handles DTPAcquDt.MouseUp
        MyEventCounter = MyEventCounter + 1
End Sub
Private Sub DTPAcquDt_ValueChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles DTPAcquDt.ValueChanged
        TxtDtAcqu.Text = DTPAcquDt.Value
        'RESET The Counter
        MyEventCounter = 0
End Sub
```