# Delphi: de-focus TDateTimePicker control

Tags: delphi, focus, selection, datetimepicker

I have the following problems with the `TDateTimePicker` control:

1. When the form comes up, it's automatically focused. It's my first control on the form, but everything needs to be de-focused on startup. I tried the following:

   ```
   procedure TfrmMain.FormShow(Sender: TObject);
   begin
     // ...
     // Defocus everything
     Self.ActiveControl := nil; // Does not work
   end;
   ```
2. Also, there is a `TSpeedButton` which should de-focus this control, but pressing it doesn't remove the focus from the `TDateTimePicker`. (Other controls like a regular `TButton` do remove it.)

   [image: month selected in DateTimePicker]

Comment: The `TDateTimePicker` has a **selection**, while your `TSpeedButton` has the **focus**. Multiple controls can have the former at the same time, while the latter is only available to one control. You want to remove a selection, not the focus. Those are two VERY different things (a focus can't be copied to the clipboard). In earlier Windows versions the focus was more distinctive (dotted line).

Comment: `TSpeedButton` is a *graphical* control, it *can't* have input focus.  `TButton` and `BitBtn` are *windowed* controls, which *can* have input focus.

Comment: @AmigoJack: I'm afraid you are incorrect in two ways: (1) A `TDateTimePicker` control hides its selection when it loses focus; the date time picker only shows a selection when focused. Hence, since the OP's date time picker has a visible selection, it must have keyboard focus. (2) The `TSpeedButton` is a graphic control, not a windowed control, so it isn't a window (no HWND) and it cannot have focus.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Yes, you're right. The screenshots could have shown a mouse cursor tho. I thought [using `DTM_GETDATETIMEPICKERINFO` to then set `ES_NOHIDESEL` of the Edit control](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43589650/4299358) should be possible, but it won't work since it's no permanent control (`TEdit.HideSelection` is the feature I was expecting to work on any Edit control).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> When the form comes up, it's automatically focused. It's my first control on the form, but everything needs to be de-focused on startup.

That is a very strange requirement. My gut feeling is that your design is suboptimal. You shouldn't fight the OS and its conventions – you should try to adhere to the norms the users expect on the platform.

> Also, there is a `TSpeedButton` which should de-focus this control, but pressing it doesn't remove the focus from the `TDateTimePicker`.

That's expected, since `TSpeedButton` is a graphic control, not a windowed control. Hence, a speed button isn't a window (like a regular button, edit box, radio button, checkbox, combo box, list box, list view, etc. is).

In particular, this means that users cannot move to your button using the keyboard (Tab), so speed buttons make your GUI less accessible and less convenient to use.

I never use speed buttons for this reason.

> everything needs to be de-focused on startup

But if you absolutely insist, you can make everything defocused from the beginning.

You only need to add an `OnActivate` handler that sets the form's `ActiveControl` to `nil`:

```pascal
procedure TForm1.FormActivate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  ActiveControl := nil
end;
```

Comment: Yes, `ActiveControl := nil` in `OnActivate` worked. My mistake was that I was doing it in `OnShow`. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

You can set its [`TabStop`](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Vcl.Controls.TWinControl.TabStop) property to false in order to prevent it from getting the initial focus.

Note that this will also prevent the user from using the <kbd>TAB</kbd> key to shift focus to the `TDateTimePicker` as well.

The reason why pressing a `TSpeedButton` does not shift focus from the `TDateTimePicker` is the fact that `TSpeedButton` is not a focusable control.

Comment: (But I would avoid any application in which I cannot navigate the GUI using the keyboard.)